# Join a table to a parcel layer and get duplicate parcels, reflecting individual leases

Tags: arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, attribute-joins, parcel

I have a table of 3,000+ lease files that I'm trying to join to our parcel layer. Each parcel has 4+ leases associated with it, and I need each to be represented by an actual polygon.  When I do a traditional join it joins 1 to 1, so it shows 1 of the 4 leases and the others do not join at all. Is it possible to join 1 parcel to many leases and have each show up as an individual polygon?
I'm using Arc 10.1.

Thanks in advance, 
Matt

Comment: If you have not seen it the page [**Deciding between relationship classes, relates, and joins**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004t00000002000000) may be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the make query tool in data management.
[arcgis resource center says it like this.](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/37544)
I just saw this 1:M tip on arcgis support website.
There does seem to be some other usable information here.
[Quick tip to perform 1:Many join](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/05/10/a-quick-tip-on-performing-a-1m-join/)

Comment: Thank you Brad! I'd tried doing a spatial join, but it wouldn't work since only one of the tables was part of a feature class, but the Make Query Tool worked perfectly and just saved me days. Thanks again!